# Counting items based on multiple criteria including multiple date constraints in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to count, per month, all the matches that meet criteria based on Project, Status, and Priority. Priority is broken into three pieces based on age.

So for January, I want the sum for all matches that are:
in January (Created_Date)
Have not yet been closed (Status)
and if a certain priority (priority) to check the age against today's date

Everything was working until I try to add in the nested SUMIFS which should be:

Minor: Count if older than 30 days old
Major: Count if older than 14 days old
Blocker: Count if older than 1 day old

My current formula:

`=(SUM(COUNTIFS(Status, {'Controls'!$P:P}, Project, $A13, Created_Date,">="&DATE(Controls!$A$1,Controls!B$1,1),Created_Date"<"&EDATE(DATE(Controls!$A$1,Controls!B$1,1), 1), SUMIFS(Priority, "Minor", Created_Date,"<"&EDATE(TODAY(),-1),(Priority, "Major", Created_Date,"<"&EDATE(TODAY(),DAY(14)),(Priority, "Blocker", Created_Date,"<"&EDATE(TODAY(),DAY(1))))))))`

Comment: I think maybe I need to use nested IF's and return TRUE which I'm hoping will add to the total count?

Answer (score 0):

```
    =ArrayFormula(SUM
(COUNTIFS(Status, {Controls!$P:$P}, Project, $A$1, Created_Date,">="&DATE(Controls!$A$1,Controls!B$1,1), Created_Date, "<"&EDATE(DATE(Controls!$A$1,Controls!B$1,1), 1),
Priority, "Minor", Created_Date,"<"&TODAY()-30),

COUNTIFS(Status, {Controls!$P:$P}, Created_Date,">="&DATE(Controls!$A$1,Controls!B$1,1), Created_Date, "<"&EDATE(DATE(Controls!$A$1,Controls!B$1,1), 1),
Priority, "Major", Created_Date,"<"&TODAY()-14),

COUNTIFS(Status, {Controls!$P:$P}, Created_Date,">="&DATE(Controls!$A$1,Controls!B$1,1), Created_Date, "<"&EDATE(DATE(Controls!$A$1,Controls!B$1,1), 1),
Priority, "Blocker", Created_Date,"<"&TODAY()-1)))
```